# Forward menu Shortcuts to other JFrame

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In my Java Swing GUI I have a main window with JMenus and shortcuts, and the possibility to open a second window to see some detail information.

When having clicked somewhere in the the second window, the menu shortcuts no longer work -- of course, it is another window than the one where the menu resides.

How can I "forward" the key events from the second window to the main window? My first idea was to let the main window implement `KeyListener` and put `getJMenuBar().dispatchEvent(...)` into the relevant methods, but while thinking about that, I saw lots of *Do **not** use KeyListeners in Swing!* statements on SO.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) This seems more a case for [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: Use `KeyBinding`s instead, see the answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40944066/2180785) and probably you might want to use `KeyStroke` and `setAccelerator(...)` as shown in the answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366793/how-do-you-make-menu-item-jmenuitem-shortcut) for the shortcuts

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm so sleepy that I didn't thought about the Card Layout right now... but agree with that

Comment: Use [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the functionality for use in in multiple views.

Comment: Short answer is, don't.  Move what ever functionality you need to the currently focused window, as trashgod says, make use of the `Action` API to reduce possible code duplication

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do anything with the source of the second window. It is a closed-source component. All I can do is calling its public (swing) methods.